# Select a record when the timestamp has passed by a certain amount of time MYSQL/PHP

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

I'm trying to select sessions that are younger than 6 hours old with this query like so:

```
"SELECT * FROM sessions WHERE members=1 AND ipRCreator != '$usn' AND tStamp < DATE_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 6 HOURS";
```

**The problem is that the query condition is always false and never manages to find the sessions even when a record actually has a timeStamp of a few seconds ago.**

obviously I am very sure that the problem is in the condition of the:

> tStamp < DATE_SUB (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 6 HOURS)

I insert the data records in the table like this:

```
 $timestamp = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
 $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO sessions (sessionId, members, ipRCreator, tStamp) VALUES('$sId', 1, '$usn', '$timestamp');") ;
```

I thought the problem was the formatting of the date but I don't think since the insert works well and the date is correctly inserted in the DB.

This is the sql structure of the table:

```
`sessionId` text NOT NULL,
  `members` int NOT NULL,
  `ipRCreator` text NOT NULL,
  `gender` text CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci NOT NULL,
  `age` int NOT NULL,
  `tStamp` timestamp NOT NULL,
  `id` int NOT NULL
```

**Where could the problem be? Why does the condition never come true?**

Sample record:
[image]

So as in this case, I'm trying to fetch this record since the timeStamp is less than 6 hours old with the query I showed; the problem is that the return query is null, it is as if there were no records that have a timeStamp younger than 6 hours (even if it is older it does not work)

Comment: A timestamp *of a few seconds ago* would certainly not be returned by the query which returns rows with a timestamp older than 6 hours ago.

Comment: @forpas What do you mean?

Comment: @forpas I was wrong in the question, I meant the sessions younger than 6 hours not the other way around. I corrected

Comment: Then reverse the inequality sign.

Comment: @forpas in both cases (whether it is> or when it is <) the query never returns anything, so I think it is not a logical problem

Comment: I don't know if there is another problem because you did not post any sample data. What I know is that there is a logical problem with your code.

Comment: @forpas I have updated the post, I hope it is clearer

Comment: You have `WHERE members=1` in your code. How do you expect to get a row with `members=2`?

Comment: @forpas it was just an example record, the same thing happens when members is at 1

Comment: @forpas anyway i'm going to correct the image

Comment: Then your problem is not reproducible. Can you reproduce it with sample data in a fiddle:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0?

Comment: (Possible) side note: Do not use string interpolation or concatenation to get values into SQL queries. That's error prone and might make your program vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. Use parameterized queries. See ["How to include a PHP variable inside a MySQL statement"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537377/how-to-include-a-php-variable-inside-a-mysql-statement) and ["How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem I used this query:

```
SELECT * FROM sessions WHERE members=1 AND ipRCreator != '$usn' AND TIMEDIFF(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, tStamp) < '06:00:00'
```